# Running copy command in docker python can't handle asterisk

Tags: python, docker, python-docker

I am trying to run a docker container to copy files from a volume to a local folder:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
stdout = client.containers.run(
    "alpine",
    mounts=[
        docker.types.Mount(
            "/data_to",
            os.path.abspath("./data_localhost"),
            'bind')
    ],
    volumes={
        volume_name: {'bind': '/data_from', 'mode': 'rw'}
    },
    working_dir='/data_from',
    command=["cp", "/data_from/*", "/data_to/"]
    # command=["touch", "/data_to/a"]
    # command=["ls", "/data_from/"]
)
logging.info(stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```

But I get

```
docker.errors.ContainerError: Command '['cp', '/data_from/*', '/data_to/']' in image 'alpine' returned non-zero exit status 1: b"cp: can't stat '/data_from/*': No such file or directory\n"
```

It seems to not handle the asterisk correctly. Why is this?

I can ls the content of `/data_from/` correctly and also write data to `/data_to/` from within the container.

Comment: Gobbling probably doesn't work because command runs with `sh`, not `bash`

Comment: Also, not clear what you're trying to copy. The working of `/data_from` starts empty... Or are you trying to extract data from a docker volume?

Comment: yes, i am trying to get the data out of an already filled volume

Comment: Why can't you use `cp -r /data_from /data_to`? Or maybe even `rsync`?